# Echad Veshishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred sixty-one (261)?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible.*

*At some point between twenty-four hours and a few days from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting, relevant answers.*
- *Accept the what I think is the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

Comment: I thought we stopped  the riddles

Comment: @Chalutzhanal: this one's kind of been grandfathered in. Besides, Isaac should get a little extra latitude for being the founder of the site.

Comment: @Chalutzhanal: This is not a [tag:riddle]-type question, which is a question where the asker knows an answer and deliberately pretends not to so that he can omit facts from his question which will make the answer obvious. See also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/140.

Comment: @Alex I do not want or claim any special latitude. I agree with msh210 that these questions do not have the same pitfalls as riddles. They are atypical in other ways, though, and anyone who wants to challenge whether they belong here is welcome to do so on [meta].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

261 days after the start of Pesach is Asara B'Teveis. (Chesvan/Kisleiv K'Sidran)

Answer (score 2):

The actual gematriah for `HaDevariim` (The book of Devariim)

And the gematriah for obama is 261: http://www.gematrix.org/?word=barrack%20obama

Answer (score 0):

261 years from *Yitzchak*'s birth to *Yosef*'s death. ([151 years to his birth](http://web.archive.org/web/20070816193605/www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/torah_timeline.html) and [another 110 thereafter](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A0_%D7%9B%D7%95).)