# Shnayim Veshishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred sixty-two (262)?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible.*

*At some point between twenty-four hours and a few days from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting, relevant answers.*
- *Accept the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

*I, for one, don't mind that these are taking a little longer these days.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

262 is the gematria of אל מלך נאמן.

Comment: In the mesoratic text of Tanach this is true, however in various commentaries (including unkelus) and in other places it is spelled maleh.

Comment: The gematria is no longer faulty and/or inaccurate. I think that this gematria is relevant and accurate and not just a random string of words, it is a meaningful, well-known, oft-used phrase.

Answer (score 5):

Avinu Malkeinu which was authored by Rabbi Akiva has 262 words - the same as the Gematria עקיבא יסדה.

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40439&st=%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%91%D7%90+%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%94

Answer (score 1):

Stealing [an answer of Gershon Gold's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8974):

There are 262 days from the first day of *Pesach* to the tenth of *Teves*, when *Cheshvan* has thirty days.